# How to improve postgres query efficiency

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I am attempting to pull a subset of a postgres table using the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.id as d_id, z.pcd as d_pcd, z.forename as d_forename, z.surname as d_surname, z.first as d_first, z.last as d_last, z.eastings as d_eastings, z.northings as d_northings, z.rn as d_rn
            FROM table1 z 
            INNER JOIN (
                SELECT DISTINCT a.id, b.first
                FROM table1 a
                INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT fullname, first FROM MatView1) b
                ON (a.fullname = b.fullname)) x
            ON z.id = x.id
            WHERE z.last <= (x.first+1) and z.last >= (x.first-3);
```

Table1 contains 145 million rows and 30 columns. The columns *id*, *fullname*, *first* and *last* are indexed but since there are duplicates that are necessary to be retained, setting a primary key on these variables are not possible. *id* and *fullname* are text string columns, whilst *first* and *last* are integer year values.

MatView1 is a materialised view of the subset of fullnames that I wish to use as the basis to retrieve a particular subset of the data. It contains approximately 200,000 fullnames, some of which may be duplicated.

I believe the nested inner joins specified in this query is necessary since I require all id's where fullname match fullname from the two tables in x, that are then further subset based on the conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

I have ran an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on the query, which describe the following query plan:

```
"Unique  (cost=233871968.33..244234487.69 rows=143516672 width=74) (actual time=909563.935..910207.026 rows=1130680 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=10742190 read=22436208, temp read=10707753 written=10713847"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=233871968.33..234814015.54 rows=376818886 width=74) (actual time=909563.933..909957.546 rows=1130680 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: z.id, z.pcd, z.forename, z.surname, z.first, z.last, z.eastings, z.northings, z.rn"
"        Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 99472kB"
"        Buffers: shared hit=10742190 read=22436208, temp read=10707753 written=10713847"
"        ->  Gather  (cost=39807897.35..113221768.36 rows=376818886 width=74) (actual time=844994.248..906225.121 rows=1130680 loops=1)"
"              Workers Planned: 2"
"              Workers Launched: 2"
"              Buffers: shared hit=10742184 read=22436208, temp read=10684975 written=10691023"
"              ->  Merge Join  (cost=39806897.35..75538879.76 rows=157007869 width=74) (actual time=844988.880..905816.659 rows=376893 loops=3)"
"                    Merge Cond: (z.id = a.id)"
"                    Join Filter: ((z.last <= (b.first + 1)) AND (z.last >= (b.first - 3)))"
"                    Rows Removed by Join Filter: 3086353"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=10742184 read=22436208, temp read=10684975 written=10691023"
"                    ->  Sort  (cost=24584683.47..24734180.01 rows=59798613 width=74) (actual time=442706.553..492701.960 rows=47784204 loops=3)"
"                          Sort Key: z.id"
"                          Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4216944kB"
"                          Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4242552kB"
"                          Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 4203736kB"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=10 read=8291416, temp read=7148113 written=7154071"
"                          ->  Parallel Seq Scan on table1 z  (cost=0.00..8889402.13 rows=59798613 width=74) (actual time=1.635..146825.594 rows=47784263 loops=3)"
"                                Buffers: shared read=8291416"
"                    ->  Materialize  (cost=15222213.88..15343607.04 rows=6069658 width=16) (actual time=402282.178..404494.609 rows=4107624 loops=3)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=10742174 read=14144792, temp read=3536862 written=3536952"
"                          ->  Unique  (cost=15222213.88..15267736.31 rows=6069658 width=16) (actual time=402282.168..404197.446 rows=1251970 loops=3)"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=10742174 read=14144792, temp read=3536862 written=3536952"
"                                ->  Sort  (cost=15222213.88..15237388.02 rows=6069658 width=16) (actual time=402282.165..403893.050 rows=1388044 loops=3)"
"                                      Sort Key: a.id, b.first"
"                                      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 38280kB"
"                                      Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 38280kB"
"                                      Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 38280kB"
"                                      Buffers: shared hit=10742174 read=14144792, temp read=3536862 written=3536952"
"                                      ->  Hash Join  (cost=12514199.34..14330904.28 rows=6069658 width=16) (actual time=306633.836..397293.362 rows=1388044 loops=3)"
"                                            Hash Cond: (b.fullname = a.fullname)"
"                                            Buffers: shared hit=10742160 read=14144792, temp read=3514146 written=3514146"
"                                            ->  Subquery Scan on b  (cost=12587.22..12957.18 rows=18498 width=18) (actual time=432.249..470.094 rows=89294 loops=3)"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=96 read=12576"
"                                                  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=12587.22..12772.20 rows=18498 width=18) (actual time=432.247..457.108 rows=89294 loops=3)"
"                                                        Group Key: matview1.fullname, matview1.first"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=96 read=12576"
"                                                        ->  Seq Scan on matview1  (cost=0.00..9799.48 rows=557548 width=18) (actual time=21.418..252.257 rows=557548 loops=3)"
"                                                              Buffers: shared hit=96 read=12576"
"                                            ->  Hash  (cost=9726582.72..9726582.72 rows=143516672 width=26) (actual time=306035.037..306035.038 rows=143352788 loops=3)"
"                                                  Buckets: 65536 (originally 65536)  Batches: 8192 (originally 4096)  Memory Usage: 3585kB"
"                                                  Buffers: shared hit=10742032 read=14132216, temp written=2455650"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on table1 a  (cost=0.00..9726582.72 rows=143516672 width=26) (actual time=1.108..233726.194 rows=143352788 loops=3)"
"                                                        Buffers: shared hit=10742032 read=14132216"
"Planning Time: 22.971 ms"
"Execution Time: 910271.228 ms"
```

I would like to make this query as efficient as possible. How might I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: joning tables by fullname, is a sign if bad design, also your tabele doesn't look like they are normalized, maybe a ERD of your tables will give a hint and sample data

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions and index definitions in addition to the output of EXPLAIN. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what useful thing this query is doing because it is hard to reverse engineer that just from the query itself and your description and the column names.  Without that, it is hard to know how it could be re-done in a top-down fashion.  So, just looking at it bottom-up....

You describe (I think) three single-column indexes.  One key to getting a better performance might be a combined index `on table1 (id, last)`.  Although I don't know if the planner would choose to use that index if it did exist, without some further persuasion (or indeed, if it would be faster if it did use it--reading all of table1 is obviously slow, but descending an index 1.2e6 times is not a picnic either).

Your subquery "x" could be optimized separately because a far as I can tell the planner plans it separately.  Just pull the text of that subquery and run it on its own.  It is bit of a mystery to my why it decides to full scan table1 as "a", rather than using a nested loop to probe the index on a.fullname 18,498 times.  That would seem a lot more efficient.  If you run that query on its own, then run it again after setting enable_hashjoin=off, comparing those plans could be informative.  If it had the ability to do an index-only scan, that might persuade it.  That would need an index `on table1 (fullname, id)` and you would also want to freshly VACUUM the table to make sure the visibility map is tuned up.